# Armatures/Rig Deforms Mesh With Extreme Angles

Tags: modeling, mesh, rigging, armature, pose-mode

I'm learning rigging and in the process of setting up a free spider man mesh (https://www.cgtrader.com/free-3d-models/character/man/base-mesh-spider-man) I noticed that in pose mode when doing extreme angles on the bones that the mesh gets kinda...wonky:

[image]

[image]

I know how to setup limits on the rotation of bones but I was wondering if I could combine that with a mesh solution? I haven't learned weight painting or vertex groups yet but should I look into that in order to stop this mesh deformation?

Comment: The first thing to ask when seeing bad deformations is, is this a reasonable position for my bones?  In your case, it is not.  Your arm positions would require clavicle involvement-- ie, you can't bend your arms that way, not without also bending your shoulders.  For doing the splits, your leg bones are placed slightly low, and you could benefit from having some helper bones at the hips to hold the pelvis weights, although in my experience, doing the splits is sort of advanced, and making it look good requires a more complicated armature than you have.

Comment: in this situations combining shape keys and drivers could help, for example changing the mesh based on leg bones

Comment: I figured my rig was too simple for this "realistic" of a mesh so I'll look into adding more armatures for these types of meshes going forward and using more bones like the clavicle and adding more for connecting the pelvis to the femur (yes I just watched this to jog my memory lol: https://youtu.be/f8zQel-jAUY). As for shape keys and drivers, I'll look into those later. Fow now I just want to get better at rigging before I start learning other tools.